# If $(x_n)_n$ is an enumeration (sequence) of $\mathbb Q\cap[0,1]$, then is it statistically convergent? Also, what is about almost convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, intuition

Since, $\mathbb Q\cap[0,1]$ is an countably infinite set, then there exists a bijection (enumeration) from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb Q\cap[0,1]$, which gives us a sequence in $\mathbb Q\cap[0,1]$.

If $(x_n)_n$ is a sequence of enumeration of $\mathbb Q\cap[0,1]$, then it can be easily verified that this sequence is not convergent in usual sense.

But my question is about the [almost convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_convergent_sequence) and [statistically convergence](https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/136236/MathSlov_30-1980-2_6.pdf) of the above sequence.

**My Question :** If $(x_n)_n$ is a sequence of enumeration of $\mathbb Q\cap[0,1]$, then is it statistically convergent? Also, what is about almost convergent here?

Comment: I think those should be two separate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following enumeration of $\mathbb Q\cap [0,1]$:
$$
\Bigl(\bigl(\frac{i}{n}\bigr)_{i=0}^n\Bigr)_{n=1}^{\infty}
$$
(Note that the fractions are not reduced, so it is not a  bijective enumeration - but this is a relatively small detail.)

For every $x\in[0,1]$ and $\epsilon\in (0,1/2)$, the set of $(i,n)$ with $|x-i/n|<\epsilon$ has density $2\epsilon$, since for all $n$ sufficiently large, there are roughly $2\epsilon n$ values of $i$ satisfying the inequality for the given $n$. (Something similar should also occur for the variant of this enumeration with duplicate fractions removed.) Thus, this particular enumeration does not converge statistically to any number.

I believe the same sequence also provides a counterexample to the almost convergence question, as well.

Comment: Are you saying about $\delta\{(i,n)\in\mathbb N\times\mathbb N: |x-\frac{i}{n}|<\epsilon\}=0$?

Comment: @BijanDatta no, what you wrote is not quite right: 1. the domain is wrong (it allows $i$ to be greater than $n$) 2. $\delta$ is not defined on $\mathbb N\times \mathbb N$. Instead, what I am saying is to reindex the $(i,n)$ pairs in order of increasing $i$, then increasing $n$ (so that it is ultimately indexed by $\mathbb N$). Sequence starts $(0,1),(1,1),(0,2),(1,2),(2,2),(0,3),\ldots$. And $\delta$ in my answer is taken with respect to this ordering.